# How to get the total spent hour per day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column here and I need to get the hour count per day (every succeeding hour +1)

[image]

Expected Output:

```
Date       | HourSpent
2017-12-08 | 6
```

My Code attempt:

```
SELECT Cast(TransDateTime as Date), DateDIFF(hour,MIN(TransDateTime),MAX(TransDateTime)) as DateTime 
FROM GuestTransLedger where GuestExtID = '2016-120-5624873' 
GROUP BY Cast(TransDateTime as Date) ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: I can't see images because of my proxy. Would you rather post the informations **as text** rather than images? (Note that using text, we can copy/paste your datas and do tests easier than re-typing everything)

Comment: Thats quite simple. What have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT Cast(TransDateTime as Date),DateDIFF(hour,MIN(TransDateTime),MAX(TransDateTime)) as DateTime FROM GuestTransLedger 
where GuestExtID = '2016-120-5624873'
GROUP BY Cast(TransDateTime as Date)
ORDER BY 1 DESC 

i tried this script but , it doesnt show exact hour spent

Comment: @ReymondJaron I added your code to the question. (where it belongs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select convert(date, datetime_column) as Date, count(distinct datepart(hour,datetime_column)) as HourSpent
from tbl
group by convert(date, datetime_column)
```

Answer (score 1):

The calendar table approach might be a good choice here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT '2017-12-08 00:00:00' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-12-08 01:00:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-12-08 02:00:00' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT '2017-12-08 22:00:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-12-08 23:00:00'
)

SELECT
    CONVERT(date, t1.dt) AS Date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t1.dt) AS HoursSpent
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.DateTime >= t1.dt AND t2.DateTime < DATEADD(HOUR, 1, t1.dt)
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(date, t1.dt);
```

The only tricky part of this answer is generating the hourly calendar table.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51952290/generate-a-calendar-table-with-hours-of-the-day-using-sql-server-2012) for one way to do this in SQL Server.