Inserting Rows Through a View by Column
My requirement is this: I have a view that returns a recordset where for each change in value of the DeviceStatus column, I set the Flag column to 1.
This way I can then calculate the total duration of that status. The problem is when the duration “overflows” into the next hour, because I would like another record with the new hour.
The query is this.
SELECT        
    EventTime, DeviceStatus, DeviceName,
    CASE 
        WHEN DeviceStatus = LAG(DeviceStatus) OVER (ORDER BY EventTime)     
            THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
    END AS Flag
FROM            
    [EventSourcing].[Fact].[Operations]
WHERE
    (DeviceName LIKE 'Device%') 
    AND DateID in (20241129,20241130)
ORDER BY
    1

A specific case is this one, where at 18:15:07 there is a state change that continues until 04:44:02 the following day



EventTime
DeviceName
DeviceStatus
Flag




2024-11-29 18:04:11.2361142
DeviceB
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:05:54.7418091
DeviceB
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:08:20.8451237
DeviceB
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:11:39.1074294
DeviceB
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:16:40.1076772
DeviceB
2000
1


!2024-11-30 03:44:55.2751548
DeviceB
1000
1


2024-11-29 18:08:49.8317093
DeviceA
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:08:57.3539314
DeviceA
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:09:05.1978502
DeviceA
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:09:08.6673125
DeviceA
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:09:16.1053403
DeviceA
2000
1


2024-11-29 18:09:27.3567976
DeviceA
2000
0


2024-11-29 18:09:57.3746556
DeviceA
2000
0


2024-11-29 18:15:07.8193011
DeviceA
3004
1


2024-11-30 04:44:02.7432369
DeviceA
2000
1


2024-11-30 04:45:21.7130785
DeviceA
2016
1


2024-11-30 04:46:36.8242106
DeviceA
2000
1


2024-11-30 04:53:58.1847945
DeviceA
1000
1


2024-11-30 04:56:05.6637439
DeviceA
1000
0


2024-11-30 04:56:28.4035914
DeviceA
1000
0



I wish it were like this



EventTime
DeviceName
DeviceStatus
Flag




2024-11-29 18:04:11.2361142
DeviceB
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:05:54.7418091
DeviceB
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:08:20.8451237
DeviceB
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:11:39.1074294
DeviceB
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:16:40.1076772
DeviceB
2000
1


2024-11-29 19:00:00.0000000
DeviceB
2000
0


2024-11-29 20:00:00.0000000
DeviceB
2000
0


2024-11-29 21:00:00.0000000
DeviceB
2000
0


2024-11-29 22:00:00.0000000
DeviceB
2000
0


2024-11-29 23:00:00.0000000
DeviceB
2000
0


2024-11-30 00:00:00.0000000
DeviceB
2000
0


2024-11-30 01:00:00.0000000
DeviceB
2000
0


2024-11-30 02:00:00.0000000
DeviceB
2000
0


2024-11-30 03:00:00.0000000
DeviceB
2000
0


!2024-11-30 03:44:55.2751548
DeviceB
1000
1


!2024-11-30 03:58:31.0083900
DeviceB
1000
0


!2024-11-30 04:00:29.9581687
DeviceB
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:08:49.8317093
DeviceA
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:08:57.3539314
DeviceA
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:09:05.1978502
DeviceA
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:09:08.6673125
DeviceA
1000
0


2024-11-29 18:09:16.1053403
DeviceA
2000
1


2024-11-29 18:09:27.3567976
DeviceA
2000
0


2024-11-29 18:09:57.3746556
DeviceA
2000
0


2024-11-29 18:15:07.8193011
DeviceA
3004
1


2024-11-29 19:00:00.0000000
DeviceA
3004
0


2024-11-29 20:00:00.0000000
DeviceA
3004
0


2024-11-29 21:00:00.0000000
DeviceA
3004
0


2024-11-29 22:00:00.0000000
DeviceA
3004
0


2024-11-29 23:00:00.0000000
DeviceA
3004
0


2024-11-30 00:00:00.0000000
DeviceA
3004
0


2024-11-30 01:00:00.0000000
DeviceA
3004
0


2024-11-30 02:00:00.0000000
DeviceA
3004
0


2024-11-30 03:00:00.0000000
DeviceA
3004
0


2024-11-30 04:00:00.0000000
DeviceA
3004
0


2024-11-30 04:44:02.7432369
DeviceA
2000
1


2024-11-30 04:45:21.7130785
DeviceA
2016
1


2024-11-30 04:46:36.8242106
DeviceA
2000
1


2024-11-30 04:53:58.1847945
DeviceA
1000
1


2024-11-30 04:56:05.6637439
DeviceA
1000
0


2024-11-30 04:56:28.4035914
DeviceA
1000
0



Do I necessarily have to enter records?
I wouldn't know how to do that. Thank you to anyone who can help me.

You need a calendar table. Create one or generate one with a recursive CTE. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51952290/generate-a-calendar-table-with-hours-of-the-day-using-sql-server-2012

Ok, creating the table would help me to have the data to be inserted in the EventTime column, but then how do I combine it with my query ? With a union or a Join ?

What version of SQL-Server are you using?

you need to have a calendar table with hour granuality and then union that table with existing table and do the status based flag calculation

Please clarify. Do you want a record with 2024-11-30 04:00?  You already have data within the 04:00 hour at 04:44.

Is this "!" character a typo?  !2024-11-30 03:44:55.2751548

What is DateID ?

Use event time if it exists for a given hour, otherwise use generated exact hour. For Device Status we use the value from the most recent EventTime. Updated 2024-DEC-06 07:40 to use Generate_Series instead of recursive CTE. Updated 2024-DEC-09 to include DeviceName.
--Use event time if it exists for a given hour+devicename combination,otherwise use generated exact hour
with d as (
   --Generate dates at 1 hour intervals for 48 hours
  --Crossjoin with distinct DeviceName
   SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, Hours.value -1 , '2024-11-29') dte, DeviceName
   FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,48) Hours
   CROSS JOIN 
   (SELECT distinct DeviceName 
   FROM Operations) do
  )
select isnull(o.EventTime,d.dte) as EventTime, 
  isnull(o.DeviceName, d.devicename) as devicename,
  isnull(DeviceStatus,
  (SELECT top 1 DeviceStatus FROM Operations WHERE eventtime < dte ORDER BY eventtime Desc)
  
  )  as DeviceStatus, 
  CASE WHEN o.EventTime IS NULL THEN  0
  ELSE
     CASE WHEN DeviceStatus = LAG(DeviceStatus) OVER (ORDER BY EventTime) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
  END AS Flag         
from d
LEFT JOIN  Operations o ON  o.devicename=d.devicename AND d.dte=DATEADD(HH,DATEPART(HH,o.EventTime),CAST(CAST(o.EventTime AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
WHERE    isnull(o.DeviceName, d.devicename) LIKE 'Device%'  
    AND CAST( isnull(o.EventTime,d.dte) AS DATE) in ('2024-11-29','2024-11-30')  
ORDER BY devicename desc,  isnull(o.EventTime,d.dte)

fiddle

That doesn't generate the actual device status, not sure it will work!

True. working on that part. https://dbfiddle.uk/UsvJ_RoV

Why a recursive CTE? That's about the worst way to generate a bunch of rows.

@Charlieface rCTE is the selected answer for question 51952290. There are alternatives we could try such as Tally Table.

Or GENERATE_SERIES. Or an actual numbers table.

@BartMcEndree Would be far better to either 1) mark the duplicate question as such if it's really helpful and a very similar case or 2) Do not copy-paste or use other answers as template, especially if they are not a wise way to do the job. Note the question and answer you mentioned are quite old, there are likely better options today.

@Jonas Metzler good point. Lets wait to see what version of SQL-Server Andrea Da Como is using. This will help us provide the most modern solution that will work for them.

I think it would be better to either just provide the best answer for today's version or wait OP to tell us their version before answering. I understand you want to help, but this shouldn't be so urgent we can't wait for missing information ;)

My Sql server version is 16.0.1000.6 SQL Server 2022

Query updated to use GENERATE_SERIES instead of recursive CTE as per Bogdan https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/using-of-generate_series

There is a problem...I did not specify one thing.
The filter condition on the Device, is a like...that is, the table must contain data records that are related to multiple devices
In the 'example you gave me if I add one or more devices it does not work correctly....
Further detail, the filter on time must be at least a couple of days selectable

@Andrea Da Como please provide example data that demonstrates the issues.

@Bart McEndree
Try populating the Operation table by adding a field that discriminates the device, and add the like filter that takes all of devices.
I updated my first post with the example

Is this closer to your needs? https://dbfiddle.uk/oygkwovo

Yes very good!! Thank you

My previous answer was to calculate the duration of devicestatus but as per comment changing it to add additional records for the missing hours.
EDIT :

hourgaps CTE finds all the rows where the gap between current and next row is more than an hour
houryseries CTE will generate sequence of numbers to find hours between current and next row and then datepart is subtracted so as to get data in the format of 00.00.0000 etc.

Fiddle
with eventdata as (
    select        
        eventtime, 
        devicename,
        devicestatus, 
        lead(eventtime) over (partition by devicename order by eventtime) as nexteventtime,
        case 
            when devicestatus = lag(devicestatus) over (partition by devicename order by eventtime) then 0 
            else 1 
        end as flag
    from            
        operations1
    where
        devicename in (select distinct devicename from operations1)  
        and dateid in (20241129, 20241130)
),
houregaps as (
    select 
        eventtime,
        devicename,
        devicestatus,
        nexteventtime,
        flag
    from eventdata
    where 
        datediff(hour, eventtime, nexteventtime) > 1 
),
hourlyseries as (
    select 
        eventtime,
        devicename,
        devicestatus,
        flag,
        cast(dateadd(hour, v.number, 
            dateadd(minute, -datepart(minute, eventtime), 
            dateadd(second, -datepart(second, eventtime), 
            dateadd(millisecond, -datepart(millisecond, eventtime), eventtime)))) as datetime2(0)) as missinghour
    from houregaps hg
    cross apply master.dbo.spt_values v
    where v.type = 'p' 
        and dateadd(hour, v.number, 
            dateadd(minute, -datepart(minute, eventtime), 
            dateadd(second, -datepart(second, eventtime), 
            dateadd(millisecond, -datepart(millisecond, eventtime), eventtime)))) < hg.nexteventtime
        and dateadd(hour, v.number, 
            dateadd(minute, -datepart(minute, eventtime), 
            dateadd(second, -datepart(second, eventtime), 
            dateadd(millisecond, -datepart(millisecond, eventtime), eventtime)))) > hg.eventtime
),
combineddata as (
    select 
        eventtime, 
        devicename,
        devicestatus, 
        flag
    from eventdata
    union all
    select 
        missinghour as eventtime, 
        devicename,
        devicestatus, 
        0 as flag 
    from hourlyseries
)
select * 
from combineddata
order by devicename, eventtime;

Output


Hi, not exactly...my goal is what I reported in the second table i.e. to complete with rows for each hour change and report the same state.

Thanks, I have edited the answer to include the missing hourly data,let me know

There is a problem...I did not specify one thing.
The filter condition on the Device, is a like...that is, the table must contain data records that are related to multiple devices
In the 'example you gave me if I add one or more devices it does not work correctly....

Do you want to edit the question and the sample input and the sample output?

Just Edit? It's clear ? Thank you

I meant you can edit the question and I can take a look and see if the requirement is clear. I might come up with follow up questions in case of doubts :)

I have edited the code, now it shows DeviceB as well.
Note: There are 2 extra rows in your output, which are not present in input, as per my understanding these rows should not be included in output as well
2024-11-30 03:58:31.0083900 DeviceB 1000 0
2024-11-30 04:00:29.9581687 DeviceB 1000 0

Nice, very good @Samhita
I should have solved everything now

If you can use generate_series and apply it with cross apply
to add the missing rows in case it is necessary.
see example
select 
   case when value=0 then EventTime
   else dateadd(hour,value,datetrunc(hour,EventTime))
   end EventTime
  ,DeviceStatus
  ,case when value=0 then Flag else 0 end Flag
  ,value,hdiff
from(
SELECT EventTime, DeviceStatus, 
    CASE WHEN DeviceStatus = LAG(DeviceStatus) OVER (ORDER BY EventTime) THEN 0 
    ELSE 1 
    END AS Flag
   ,lead(EventTime,1,EventTime)over(order by EventTime) nextTime
   ,datediff(minute,EventTime,lead(EventTime,1,EventTime)over(order by EventTime)) hdiff
FROM Operations
 -- where devicename like 'DEVICEA' and dateid in (20241129, 20241130)
)a
cross apply generate_series(0,datediff(minute,EventTime,nextTime)/60) sn

We use datediff(minute,EventTime,nextTime)/60 instead datediff(hour,EventTime,nextTime) for cases like
,('2024-11-30 04:56:28.4035914',    1000)
,('2024-11-30 05:00:00.0000000',    5000)

there first value is 0 and second is 1. We wait 0.
fiddle
